# Multisite: How to get a list of sites by locale

Tags: multisite

In a network install, sites may be using a different locale. How can I get a list of all sites using a given locale? For example `ja`

I tried using WP_Site_Query but this didn't work. For example

`$query = WP_Site_Query( ['lang_id' => 'ja'] );`

Comment: In [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/WP_Site_Query/__construct/), it says that the `lang_id` is an `int`, not a string.

Comment: @PatJ that is the reason why my attempt failed. also, the `lang_id` field in the `wp_blogs` table isn't actually used